# How to keep primefaces rowexpansion open in an update of the table?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Hi I have a datatable with a p:rowToggler, so when launch a popup from a row expasion, after I close the popup I need to update some labels in the rows. Update works! but  the row expanded, collapse. How can you keep open the rowexpansion after close the popup and updated the content. thanks.

Snippet of PopUp

> ```
>  <p:ajax event="close"  update=":id1:id2"  oncomplete="someJavascript()" />
> ```

Snippet of Databable

```
<h:form prependId="false" id="id1"> 
            <h:panelGroup id="id2" >
                  <p:dataTable tableStyleClass="win" var="element"                                id="table1" value="#{myBean.list}"
                            selectionMode="single"  rowExpandMode="single" rowIndexVar="cont" widgetVar="table1"
                           selection="#{myBean.selectedRecord}" rowKey="#{element.id}"   >
<p:ajax event="rowToggle"    listener="#{myBean.methodBean(element)}" /> 
                     <p:column styleClass="rowTogglerStyle" 
<p:rowToggler collapseLabel="#{bundle.show}" 
 expandLabel="#{bundle.show}">
</p:rowToggler>                    
</p:column> 

</p:datatable>  </h:panelGroup>  </h:form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi the problem was that the selected rowexpansion after close the popup had the class ui-state-highlight yet, so  I found to do this to reopen the closed rowexpansion via javascript in onclomplete atributte in p:ajax :

jQuery('tr.ui-state-highlight').find('td.rowTogglerStyle  > div.ui-row-toggler').trigger('click');

I hope it will be useful for someone else.

Answer (score 2):

If you save your expanded row element id you can do it like that:

```
<p:dataTable expandedRow="#{element.id == myBean.expandedRowElementId}">
    <p:ajax event="rowToggle" listener="#{bean.setExpandedRowElementId(element.id)}"/>
```

To prevent it of being opened again you need to modify the setter a bit:

```
public void setExpandedRowElementId(String expandedRowElementId){
  if(this.expandedRowElementId != null && expandedRowElementId.equals(this.expandedRowElementId) 
  // if the id is equal the expansion is closed, so the expanded element must be set to null
     this.expandedRowElementId = null;
  else
     this.expandedRowElementId = expandedRowElementId;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @lastresort I am trying it.